# TextViews no se adaptan a la configuracion de tamaño nativa

Tags: java, android

Mi aplicación no toma la configuración nativa por configuración

Si voy a Opciones - Zoom y tamaño de letra y vuelvo a mi aplicación siempre me muestra el mismo tamaño - Encontré que debería usar SP en vez de DP

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16sp</dimen>
<dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16sp</dimen>

<!--Tamaño de textos-->
<dimen name="simple_text_size_big">30sp</dimen>
<dimen name="simple_text_size">17sp</dimen>
<dimen name="simple_text_size_very_big">25sp</dimen>
<dimen name="simple_text_size_small">13sp</dimen>
<dimen name="simple_text_size_very_small">10sp</dimen>
<dimen name="simple_text_size_small_big">14sp</dimen>

<!--Padding-->
<dimen name="page_padding_top_principal">30sp</dimen>
<dimen name="page_padding_top">10sp</dimen>
<dimen name="page_padding">10sp</dimen>
<dimen name="page_padding_top_big">15sp</dimen>
<dimen name="page_padding_top_small">5sp</dimen>
<dimen name="page_padding_bottom_small">5sp</dimen>
<dimen name="page_padding_bottom_big">15sp</dimen>
<dimen name="page_padding_left_small">5sp</dimen>
<dimen name="page_padding_left">10sp</dimen>
<dimen name="page_padding_right">10sp</dimen>
<dimen name="page_padding_left_double">20sp</dimen>
<dimen name="page_padding_right_double">20sp</dimen>
<dimen name="slide_menu_padding">10sp</dimen>
<dimen name="slide_menu_margin">15sp</dimen>

<!--Margim-->
<dimen name="page_margin_top_principal">30sp</dimen>
<dimen name="page_margin_top">10sp</dimen>
<dimen name="page_margin_top_double">20sp</dimen>
<dimen name="page_margin_top_small">5sp</dimen>
<dimen name="page_margin_bottom_small">5sp</dimen>
<dimen name="page_margin_left">10sp</dimen>
<dimen name="page_margin_right">10sp</dimen>
<dimen name="page_margin_left_big">25sp</dimen>
<dimen name="page_margin_right_big">25sp</dimen>
<dimen name="page_margin_left_double">40sp</dimen>
<dimen name="page_margin_top_big">15sp</dimen>
<dimen name="page_margin_bottom_big">20sp</dimen>
<dimen name="page_margin_bottom_double">40sp</dimen>
<dimen name="page_margin_right_double">40sp</dimen>

<!--Separador de lineas-->
<dimen name="line_separator_height">1.5sp</dimen>
<dimen name="line_separator">1sp</dimen>
<dimen name="toolbar_height">45sp</dimen>
<dimen name="button_height">50sp</dimen>
<dimen name="toolbar_margin">10sp</dimen>
<dimen name="table_title_heigh">40sp</dimen>
<dimen name="bankLogo_height">170sp</dimen>
<dimen name="bankLogo_width">230sp</dimen>
<dimen name="appTitle_height">225sp</dimen>
<dimen name="appTitle_width">45sp</dimen>
<dimen name="home_toolbar_icon">20sp</dimen>
<dimen name="home_list_item_icon">30sp</dimen>
<dimen name="menu_margin">30sp</dimen>
<dimen name="cero">0sp</dimen>
<dimen name="rowPadding">2sp</dimen>
<dimen name="grid_item_image_width">70sp</dimen>
<dimen name="grid_item_image_height">70sp</dimen>
<dimen name="page_margin_bottom">10sp</dimen>
<dimen name="line_separator_height_thick">2sp</dimen>

<dimen name="input_label_vertical_spacing">8sp</dimen>
<dimen name="input_label_horizontal_spacing">4sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Probé con DP y SP y ninguna de las 2 hace ningún efecto

este es mi manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  package="machala.twoinnovateit.com.machalamym">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />

<protected-broadcast android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:name = "android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="machala.twoinnovateit.com.machalamym.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <!-- ressource file to create -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths">
        </meta-data>
    </provider>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCod4KJ24V8jR6O8GEC0vK2RiYZYnpMcro" />

    <activity
        android:name="machala.twoinnovateit.com.machalamym.machala.SplashInicio"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeLogin">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
        android:name="machala.twoinnovateit.com.machalamym.machala.Login.LoginPassUserActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
        android:name="machala.twoinnovateit.com.machalamym.PreLogin.ContactConfirmadaActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
        android:name="machala.twoinnovateit.com.machalamym.machala.ProductsDetailActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">


    </activity>
    <activity
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
        android:name="machala.twoinnovateit.com.machalamym.PreLogin.ContactActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
        android:name="machala.twoinnovateit.com.machalamym.PreLogin.ProductsActivityFueraDelLogin"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
        android:name="machala.twoinnovateit.com.machalamym.PreLogin.ProductsDetailActivityFueraDelLogin"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="machala.twoinnovateit.com.machalamym.PreLogin.OfficesActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="machala.twoinnovateit.com.machalamym.PreLogin.PromotionsActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="machala.twoinnovateit.com.machalamym.machala.ProductsActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
        android:name="machala.twoinnovateit.com.machalamym.machala.Transactions.Payments.PagoActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="machala.twoinnovateit.com.machalamym.machala.MainMenu.HomeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="machala.twoinnovateit.com.machalamym.machala.Login.HuellaDigitalActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="machala.twoinnovateit.com.machalamym.machala.DetalleInversionActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="machala.twoinnovateit.com.machalamym.machala.DetalleCuentaActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
        android:name=".machala.Transactions.Transfers.TransferenciaActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="machala.twoinnovateit.com.machalamym.machala.Login.InicialActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <activity
        android:name="machala.twoinnovateit.com.machalamym.machala.Locks.BloqueoConfirmadoActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <activity
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
        android:name="machala.twoinnovateit.com.machalamym.machala.RecoverPasswordActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <activity
        android:name="machala.twoinnovateit.com.machalamym.machala.Locks.BlockDetailTarjetaActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <activity
        android:name="machala.twoinnovateit.com.machalamym.machala.Locks.BlockDetailChequeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <activity
        android:name="machala.twoinnovateit.com.machalamym.machala.Locks.BlockActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <activity
        android:name="machala.twoinnovateit.com.machalamym.machala.BeneficiaryActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <activity
        android:name="machala.twoinnovateit.com.machalamym.machala.PantallaDeError"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <activity
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
        android:name="machala.twoinnovateit.com.machalamym.machala.ChangePasswordActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <activity
        android:name="machala.twoinnovateit.com.machalamym.machala.ChangePasswordConfirmadoActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <activity
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
        android:name="machala.twoinnovateit.com.machalamym.machala.FotoAliasActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <activity
        android:name="machala.twoinnovateit.com.machalamym.machala.RecoverPasswordConfirmation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name="machala.twoinnovateit.com.machalamym.machala.MovementsActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <activity
        android:name="machala.twoinnovateit.com.machalamym.machala.MovementsDetailsActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name="machala.twoinnovateit.com.machalamym.machala.EstadoCuentaActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".machala.Transactions.Transfers.TranferenciaConfirmadaActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name="machala.twoinnovateit.com.machalamym.machala.DetalleTarjetaActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name="machala.twoinnovateit.com.machalamym.machala.DetalleCreditoActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

</application>

</manifest>
```

TextView de ejemplo :

```
 <TextView
                android:id="@+id/forgottenPassword"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:onClick="goToRecoverPassword"
                android:text="@string/forgotten_password"
                android:textColor="@color/gris"
                android:textSize="@dimen/simple_text_size_small" />
```

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Pd: necesito que se adapte según la configuración nativa

Comment: Y el TextView donde está?

Comment: @Juan Agregado Juan

Comment: La unidad de medida definitivamente es sp. Recién hice una prueba con un TextView, y, para el mismo tamaño, cambiando el tamaño del font en configuración (chico, default, grande, o muy grande), pude ver que el tamaño del font en pantalla cambia.

Comment: Pues en teoria si pero mis textView no cambian de tamaño por eso mi pregunta por aqui algo esta bloqueandolos y no me doy cuenta que es

Comment: Te fijaste cambiando entre el mas chico y el más grande? Las diferencias por lo que ví no son "abismales".

Comment: si claro si mire detenidamente pero aun asi no son exactamentes iguales

Comment: Realmente me parece exagerado que tengas que recurrir a métodos algo oscuros como manipulaciones del layout por este motivo. Si los `textView` no se adaptan al tamaño de la configuración del dispositivo debe ser que hay algo mal seteado en algún rincón de tu dispositivo (el mismo `textView` cuyo tamaño es cambiado por programación, alguna configuración o preferencia que trabaja de forma oscura en tu app, que la pusiste un día y no te acuerdas, etc). Diría que, no recurras a algo oscuro para resolver una confusión oscura, saca a la luz o busca **dónde** está el problema.

Comment: @A.Cedano si el tema es que ya pense que algo me esta bloqueando ello pero no me doy cuenta ni imagino que podria hacer eso

Comment: Te dejo una más por las dudas, fijata que estés usando android:textSize y no tools:textSize.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/234540/textviews-no-se-adaptan-a-la-configuracion-de-tama%C3%B1o-nativa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para que tu `app` pueda adaptar el tamaño de fuente de la configuración nativa es decir la configuración del sistema, debes crear dimensiones, `small`, `large`, y `xlarge` en tu archivo `dimens.xml`, ya que básicamente al momento en que tú cambias el tamaño de fuente en el sistema y vas a la `app`, esta se adapta al tamaño de fuente que busca el sistema operativo por decirlo de alguna manera y la usa en la app.

Lo que debes hacer es esto:

Colocate en la vista "`Android`" luego ve al siguiente directorio `res/values`. Luego, clic derecho sobre `dimens` luego `new > Values resource file`.

- Acá te saldrá la ventana de `New Resource File`.
- En el campo `File name`: coloca `dimens` (tal cual como esta escrito).
- En `Source set : main`
- En `Directory name: values`
- Luego en la sección de la lista "`Available qualifiers`" selecciona "`Size`" Seguidamente clic en el boton "`>>`"

Te pedirá que selecciones el tamaño de pantalla, estas están clasificadas en:

- Small
- Normal
- Large
- X-Large

Seleccionas la que necesites y luego le das clic al botón "`OK`", después repetirás este mismo procedimiento para las demás densidades.

Por ultimo agregas las densidades (las mismas) únicamente cambiando su valor en cada uno de estos archivos.

si en `dimens.xml` tienes por ejemplo:

```
<dimen name="tamaño_texto_normal">15sp</dimen>
```

En `dimens.xml (large)` modificando su valor así:

```
<dimen name="tamaño_texto_normal">25sp</dimen>
```

Ya que `Android Studio` por defecto buscará el tipo de archivo que necesite según la densidad o tamaño de pantalla en la que se intente correr la aplicación, y en caso que intente buscar el mismo nombre de `dimens.xml` en `dimens.xml (large)` y no coincidan, te mandará un error de que no encuentra la dimensión especificada u otro tipo de error.

A su vez lo mismo pasa con la configuración del sistema, ¿que hace?, bueno si seleccionas en tu configuración nativa, tamaño de fuente "grande" (por ejemplo), al momento de abrir tu `app`, automáticamente el `SO` (Sistema operativo) buscará la configuración de las densidades "large" ( `dimens.xml (large)` ) y pondrá los textos de ese tamaño manteniendo las proporciones de las vistas que tengas en tu `app`, si configuras de forma nativa tamaño de fuente "pequeña", el SO al abrir la `app` buscará `dimens.xml (small)` y así sucesivamente. En tu caso solo tienes un archivo `dimens.xml`, por eso no cambia el tamaño de letra, por que el SO no encuentra otra variación de dimensiones.

Comment: Por favor hazme saber si te funcionó, saludos.

Comment: lo pondre en practica y te comento David Villegas

Comment: Si sonaba muy convincente pero no me funciono

Comment: Es extraño, actualmente uso esa forma y si me cambia las letras de tamaño sin problemas según la configuración nativa @BrunoSosaFastTag

Comment: dejare la pregunta un tiempo mas haber si alguien mas responde, sino luego te la marco porque si suena que es asi pero aun asi parece haber algo que lo bloquea

Comment: Me parece que esta respuesta aplica a cambios de tamaño de pantalla (que se vea similar en diferentes dispositivos), que es diferente de que se refleje en el mismo tamaño de pantalla los cambios de configuración en el tamaño del font. Pensa que en el mismo dimens defines tamaños que aplican a cualquier view. Y al cambiar el tamaño del font solo cambia eso. El resto de la app queda igual.

Comment: @BrunoSosaFastTag esperemos que alguien mas responda, para que puedas solucionar tu problema, por cierto, densificaste las pantallas? `layout (small)`, `layout (large)` etc?

Comment: @Juan quizás tengas razón, la cosa es que yo densifico tanto `layouts` como `dimens`, normalmente así trabajo para evitar problemas por tamaños de pantallas y textos, por eso digo, que uso este método y me funciona. Quizas el problema de @BrunoSosaFastTag sea otro.

Comment: @DavidVillegas que significa desinficar layouts dicen que hacen varios layouts de pantallas tambien con small large etc?

Comment: @BrunoSosaFastTag exacto, básicamente lo mismo que `dimens`, cual es otro de los fines tener los `dimens` densificados? que cuando densificas los `layouts` solo cambias los valores de los `dimens` en cada archivo, ya no tienes que harcodear valores en los `layouts` sino que automáticamente si el `layout` es `large`, buscara el archivo `large` de `dimens`. Esto se tiene en cuenta para compatibilidad, para que tu `app` se adapte sin problemas a diversos tamaños de pantalla.

Comment: ¿En serio que hay que hacer todo esto para que la App funcione de una forma en la que debería funcionar **normalmente**? A mi me parece un procedimiento muy complicado y creo que los esfuerzos deberían estar orientados a buscar el origen del problema. En cualquier App el tamaño del texto adopta el de la configuración del dispositivo, a no ser que haya algo en alguna parte que se lo impida. En vez de ponerme a modificar layouts yo buscaría qué es lo que hace que el tamaño del texto cambie y lo corregiría en la raíz. Lo que propones no se sabe qué efectos puede tener según ciertos dispositivos.

Comment: @A.Cedano no lo veo como complicado por que normalmente ese es el procedimiento de rutina por así decirlo para dar soporte a múltiples tamaños de pantalla, sea por una u otra razón se debe hacer, no es obligatorio pero es conveniente, ya que si haces un solo `layout` al abrilo en un equipo con dimensión `xlarge` por ejemplo, las vistas se verán extremadamente pequeñas y totalmente des proporcionales, hacer lo mismo con los recursos `dimens` mas bien facilitan el trabajo porque, básicamente todos los layouts son exactamente iguales con la diferencia que leerán su archivo dimens correspondiente.

Comment: Dicho de ese modo entonces sí tiene sentido David. Procedo a retirar mi voto negativo en ese caso. Gracias por tu aclaración. Saludos.

Comment: @A.Cedano por nada, la idea es aclarar las cosas los mas posible para llegar a las soluciones deseadas. Saludos :)